# Can DataGridView control be used to display live or real-time data?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, oxygene

Well, I have been using DataGridView to display live and real-time data on the fly. So, the user can look at the data as they are being generated. Data displayed is updated in less than a second. Although it works great, I am noticing that anytime the winform with the DataGridView is opened or displayed on the monitor, CPU percentage goes up drastically to between 15% to 20%. If not displayed, CPU % goes down to 0 to 5.

[image]

Can I use the DataGridView control the way I am using it?

Comment: How are you polling for new data?

Comment: @StuartDunkeld, I am using a thread that loops for data.

Comment: Using something like a `do while true` loop?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without your including the way you're retrieving the data. Obviously any CPU use is related as much to that as it is to the overhead of updating a DataGridView.

Comment: @StuartDunkeld, Yes exactly.

Comment: @KenWhite, You maybe right, but the question is related to usage of DataGridView. Is updating the grid too fast directly affecting the CPU usage? Apparently, it seems that way. It doesn't seem to matter how I pull the data - grid displayed CPU % goes up and not displayed CPU % goes down.

Comment: You could introduce a timer and just poll once a second. This will give effectively real-time data without punishing the CPU (and the database).

Comment: @digitalanalog: OK. The answer to the question you've asked is "Yes, the DataGridView can be used to display live or real-time data.". Or, if you'd prefer, "No, the DataGridView cannot be used to display live or real-time data.". Those are the two possible answers to the question. Good luck. :-)